# Bootstrap three column three row with third column spanned height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting to achieve the layout below using `col-lg-4`.

[image: Three rows, three columns, with third column spanning the three rows]

I just need to know how I can make the third column span all three rows and without creating enormous gaps of whitespace between the rows. Here's what it's currently looking like:

[image: Three rows, three columns, but with third column NOT spanning the three rows]

Is this possible to do in Bootstrap (*without* using the Bootstrap 2 `span` classes)?

Here's the code (generalized)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <!-- THIS NEEDS TO ROW SPAN -->
      <p>Praesent posuere egestas sagittis. Sed feugiat nibh urna, egestas elementum ipsum facilisis et. Nullam elit nisi, tincidunt a turpis ac, fringilla pellentesque nibh. Suspendisse pulvinar orci sit amet metus laoreet, sed tincidunt quam semper. Vestibulum
        ac nunc a justo vulputate venenatis vel sit amet augue. Vestibulum eu hendrerit sem. Aenean nec tempus ipsum. Integer nec lectus varius, venenatis orci vitae, efficitur mi. Curabitur at consectetur leo, sit amet consectetur nisi. Nam nec eros
        facilisis, aliquam sem molestie, auctor elit. Vivamus quis hendrerit justo, vel molestie ligula.</p>

      <p>Morbi leo magna, sollicitudin a sem ac, finibus facilisis ex. Nam ut enim commodo, venenatis augue nec, consectetur velit. Sed lobortis vitae lacus at pulvinar. Aliquam vel enim tristique, lacinia nibh ut, porta dui. Fusce efficitur volutpat lectus
        maximus iaculis. Proin purus odio, auctor id sollicitudin nec, lacinia vel ligula. Sed luctus ipsum non sem tincidunt mollis.</p>

      <p>Pellentesque congue mauris non tempor tincidunt. Phasellus pretium at lorem ut auctor. Donec rhoncus, nibh vitae aliquam tristique, leo quam elementum nisl, at porttitor massa diam venenatis diam. Suspendisse potenti. Sed gravida, mauris nec rhoncus
        feugiat, augue velit facilisis mauris, et dapibus nisl augue non nunc. Nunc pretium quam eget tincidunt sollicitudin. Etiam maximus metus eget accumsan efficitur. Fusce a lorem vitae libero blandit condimentum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use nested `col-`s, in this case, use `col-lg-8` + `col-lg-4`

and inside  `col-lg-8` you create nested `cols` using `row`

added `col-xs-*` for demo.

```css
[class*="col-"] {
  border: red dashed 1px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
          Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
          Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
          Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
          Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
          Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
          Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-lg-4">
      Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.Praesent laoreet purus in elementum.Praesent laoreet purus in elementum. Praesent
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. I think I understand how this works now.